# How can I round down to the nearest multiple of 3 in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I round an integer *down* to the nearest multiple of 3 using PHP?  And have <3 be 0.

For example:
4 becomes 3
10 becomes 9
9 becomes 9
8 becomes 6

And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for.

```
/**
 * Round an integer down to the nearest multiple of the given multiple
 * @param integer $number
 * @param integer $multiple
 * @return integer
 */
 function round_down_to_multiple_of( int $number, int $multiple = 3 ): int
 {
    return (int)($multiple * floor( $number/$multiple ));
 }

 # TESTS
 $numbers = [ 10, 9, 8, 1, 0 ];
foreach( $numbers as $number ){
    printf( '%d became %d'.PHP_EOL, $number, round_down_to_multiple_of( $number, 3 ) );
}
```

After running the above test I get the following results:

```
10 became 9
9 became 9
8 became 6
1 became 0
0 became 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$x` is your input:

```
print $x-$x%3;
```

Comment: actually this would return `9` for `x=9` because 9 - 9%3 = 9 - 0

Comment: @Martin and this is wrong because? Did you read the question?

Comment: I readded my plus one for you `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I know there are good answers here but this one is for larger numbers for the sake of alternative, using [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

```
function floor_to_multiple($number, $multiplier) {
    return bcsub($number, bcmod($number, $multiplier));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I misread that even if it is a perfect fit, it should round down to the *last* preceeding incremental:

> 4 becomes 3
>   10 becomes 9
>   9 becomes 6
>   8 becomes 6

Therefore, if for some reason you need this; your answer would be:

```
print $x-($x-1)%3-1;
```

*I made a mistake in comprehending the question but thought this answer was curious enough to be worth posting.*

Answer (score 0):

**If you want for 3, you may use function below:**

```
function round_nearest_3($value){
    return $value-$value%3;
}
```

**If you want to return function for any value use function below:**

```
function round_nearest_mod($value,$mod){
    return $value-$value%$mod;
}
```

**Examples:**

```
echo round_nearest_3(4); // becomes 3
echo round_nearest_3(10); // becomes 9
echo round_nearest_3(9); // becomes 9
echo round_nearest_3(8); // becomes 6

echo round_nearest_mod(4,3); // becomes 3
echo round_nearest_mod(10,3); // becomes 9
echo round_nearest_mod(9,3); // becomes 9
echo round_nearest_mod(8,3); // becomes 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//requested number
$num = 10;
//calc
for($i=1;($i*3)<=$num;$i++)$answer[] = $i;
$answer = max($answer)*3;
//print result
print_r($answer);
```

Comment: This algorithm is very inefficient.

Comment: yes, just a variation :/